# Spark: filter in each group

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a dataframe like

```
+------+-------------------+------+
|group |               time| label|
+------+-------------------+------+
|     a|2020-01-01 10:49:00|first |
|     a|2020-01-01 10:51:00|second|
|     a|2020-01-01 12:49:00|first |
|     b|2020-01-01 12:44:00|second|
|     b|2020-01-01 12:46:00|first |
|     c|2020-01-01 12:46:00|third |
+------+-------------------+------+
```

I would like to drop all rows where, for each group, the label `first` is more recent than label `second` or `third`. For instance in group `a` the row with `first` and `2020-01-01 12:49:00` should be dropped as there's an older row with `second` label.

The desired output would be:

```
+------+-------------------+------+
|group |               time| label|
+------+-------------------+------+
|     a|2020-01-01 10:49:00|first |
|     a|2020-01-01 10:51:00|second|
|     b|2020-01-01 12:44:00|second|
|     c|2020-01-01 12:46:00|third |
+------+-------------------+------+
```

A window function with partition by `group` would filter inside each group, but how to implement the filter on label?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the previous time with a label that is not "first", and do a filter using that column:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "non_first_time", 
    last(
        when(col("label") =!= "first", col("time")), 
        true
    ).over(
        Window.partitionBy("group").orderBy("time")
    )
).filter("""
    label != 'first' or 
    (label = 'first' and (non_first_time > time or non_first_time is null))
""").drop("non_first_time")

df2.show
+-----+-------------------+------+
|group|               time| label|
+-----+-------------------+------+
|    c|2020-01-01 12:46:00| third|
|    b|2020-01-01 12:44:00|second|
|    a|2020-01-01 10:49:00| first|
|    a|2020-01-01 10:51:00|second|
+-----+-------------------+------+
```